# Scroll position based javascript animation does not revert to it's original state when scrolling back up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, absolute

See the JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jL6d2qp6/

I have an animation that is supposed to keep the #top element in a fixed position at the top of the page, except for when the #login element is on the screen. To control this, I am using a javascript function that runs every 10ms and switches out the css class for #top, and when I scroll down, it updates as expected, but when I try to scroll back up, nothing happens.

javascript code in question:

```
offScreen = function(id, targetValue)
{
    var offset = $("#top").offset();
    var w = $(window);
    var height = $(id).innerHeight();
    var finalOffset = (offset.top + height) - w.scrollTop();
    if (finalOffset < targetValue)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

function updateTopMenu()
{
    if (offScreen("#login", 81) === false)
    {
        if($("#top").hasClass("top-bar-absolute") === false)
        {
            $("#top").addClass("top-bar-absolute");
            console.log("added top-bar-absolute");
        }
        if($("#top").hasClass("top-bar-fixed") === true)
        {
            $("#top").removeClass("top-bar-fixed");
            console.log("removed top-bar-fixed");
        }
    }
    if(offScreen("#login", 81) === true)
    {
        if($("#top").hasClass("top-bar-absolute") === true)
        {
            $("#top").removeClass("top-bar-absolute");
            console.log("removed top-bar-absolute");
        }
        if($("#top").hasClass("top-bar-fixed") === false)
        {
            $("#top").addClass("top-bar-fixed");
            console.log("added top-bar-fixed");
        }
    }
}

$("#top").ready( function() {
    setInterval(updateTopMenu, 10);
});
```

Also, if there is a better way to accomplish this, I'd like it because this feels kind of cheaty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is listening to the [**scroll**](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event on the window. This is called every time the user scrolls. Then you can check whether the user scrolled past the login box, i.e. beyond the login box's *height*.

If the login box is no longer in the window, assign the #top box a class like *.sticky* that will change its *position* to `position: fixed`. And otherwise remove this class.

Checkout this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jknzjqju/).